SAP Commerce : where can i tweak the Excel template that's used for the product export?
My goal is to include the label of the Classification Features so that they can be displayed as follows:

B00408_01.126 - Shape
B00408_01.127 - Material
B00408_01.503 - Optional catalytic conversion kit

instead of

B00408_01.126 - mycompanyClassificationCatalog/1.0
B00408_01.127 - mycompanyClassificationCatalog/1.0
B00408_01.503 - mycompanyClassificationCatalog/1.0

which is unbearable for us to work with given the amount of features we have to handle.
I noticed that the product export files contain 4 invisible sheets (xlSheetVeryHidden)
One of them is named ClassificationTypeSystem and contains the headers that I'd like to tweak.
Can anyone show me a lead? Thank you.

Where did you get product export excel file? Hyris just export the grid as excel.
